# PHP - Why am I being warned that my regular expression is too large?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use a regular expression to validate user input. I want to allow any combination of letters, numbers, spaces, commas, apostrophes, periods, exclamation marks, and question marks, but I also want to limit the input to 4000 characters. I have come up with the following regular expression to achieve this: `/^([a-z]|[0-9]| |,|'|\.|!|\?){1,4000}$/i`.

However, when I attempt to use this regular expression test a subject in PHP with preg_match(), I am given a warning: `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 37` and the subject fails to be tested.

I find this strange because if I use an infinite quantifier, the test passes just fine (I demonstrate this situation below).

**Why is limiting the repetition to 4000 a problem, but infinite repetition not?**

**regex-test.php:**

```
<?php

$infinite = "/^([a-z]|[0-9]| |,|'|\.|!|\?)*$/i";        // Allows infinite repetition
$fourk    = "/^([a-z]|[0-9]| |,|'|\.|!|\?){1,4000}$/i"; // Limits repetition to 4000

$string   = "I like apples.";

if ( preg_match($infinite, $string) ){

    echo "Passed infinite repetition. \n";
}

if ( preg_match($fourk, $string) ){

    echo "Passed maximum repetition of 4000. \n";
}

?>
```

**echos:**

```
Passed infinite repetition 
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 37 in regex-test.php on line 16
```

Comment: That's probably buried deep within [php_pcre.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c); it may compile a state machine by copying part of the regexp 4000 times, I couldn't find that without diving too deep into it. I suppose you'll have to do a `strlen` check before the regexp instead. Oh, and `*` means `any number of occurrences`, so there are no bounds whatsoever, which by definition cannot be programmed (since programs impose conditions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is due to its **`LINK_SIZE`**, with offset values limiting the compiled pattern size to 64K. This is an expected behavior, explained below, and it's not because of a limit in repetition nor how the pattern is interpreted when compiled.

---

### In this case

As Alan Moore pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977966/5290909), all characters should be in the same [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). I'm more drastic, so allow me to say that pattern is *so* wrong it makes me cringe.
<sup>-No offense, most of us tried that once too. It's just an attempt to underline that in no way such constructs should be used.</sup>

There are 3 common pitfalls here in `(x|y|z){1,4000}`:

1. [Capturing subpatterns](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) should only be used when needed (to store *a specific part* of the matched text, in order to extract that value or to use it in a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)). For all other use cases, stick to [non-capturing groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) or [atomic groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#atomic). They perform better and save memory.
2. Capturing subpatterns [should not be repeated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) because the last repetition overwrites the captured text.
   -OK, it *could* be used only in *very* particular cases.
3. [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (with the `|`<sub>s</sub>) adds backtracking states. It's a good practice to try to reduce them as much as you can. In this case, the regex `^[ !',.0-9?A-Z]{1,4000}$/i`, would match exactly the same, not only avoiding the error, but also proving better performance.

---

### LINK_SIZE

> **From "[Handling Very Large Patterns](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrebuild.html#SEC12)"** in [pcrebuild man page](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrebuild.html):
>
> Within a compiled pattern, offset values are used to point from one
>   part to another (for example, from an opening parenthesis to an
>   alternation metacharacter). By default, in the 8-bit and 16-bit 
>   libraries, two-byte values are used for these offsets, leading to a 
>   maximum size for a compiled pattern of around 64K.

That means the compiled pattern stores an offset value for every subpattern in the alternation, for every repetition of the group. In this case the offsets leave no memory for the rest of the compiled pattern.

> **This is more clearly expressed in a comment in [pcre_internal.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_internal.h#L412)** from the PHP dist:
>
> PCRE keeps offsets in its compiled code as 2-byte quantities (always
>   stored in big-endian order) by default. These are used, for example,
>   to link from the start of a subpattern to its alternatives and its
>   end. The use of 2 bytes per offset limits the size of the compiled
>   regex to around 64K, which is big enough for almost everybody.

Using **[pcretest](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcretest.html)**, I get the following information:

```
PCRE version 8.37 2015-04-28

/^([a-z]|[0-9]| |,|'|\.|!|\?){1,575}$/i
Failed: regular expression is too large at offset 36

/^([a-z]|[0-9]| |,|'|\.|!|\?){1,574}$/i
Memory allocation (code space): 65432
```

- There's a Windows version you can download from [RexEgg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html#pcretest).

Regarding other size limitations in PCRE, you can check [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928343/5290909).

---

### Overriding the default `LINK_SIZE` in PHP

If we had a true reason to use a huge pattern, and this pattern could not be simplified any further by all means, the link size could be increased. However, you can only achieve this by recompiling PHP yourself (therefore, your code won't be portable from now on). It should be the last resort, provided there's no other choice.

> **Also commented in [pcre_internal.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_internal.h#L421)**:
>
> The macros are controlled by the value of `LINK_SIZE`.
>   This defaults to 2 in the [config.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/pcrelib/config.h) file, 
>   but can be overridden by using `-D` on the command line.
>   This is automated on Unix systems via the "configure" command.

PCRE link size can be configured to 3 or 4:

```
./configure -DLINK_SIZE=4
```

But keep in mind that longer offsets require additional data, and it will slow down all calls to [`preg_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php).

In case of compiling PHP on your own, see [Installation on Unix systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php) or [Build your own PHP on Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).

Comment: Very well done. It was clearly a fundamental misunderstanding of the efficient use of regular expressions on my part. I hope this question and answer will serve other programmers with the same misunderstanding in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the 'regex' engine php uses, pcre here: http://pcre.sourceforge.net/pcre.txt at the limitations section it states:

```
The maximum length of a  compiled  pattern  is  65539  (sic)
 bytes
```

My guess is that some regex like this:

```
(123){1,3}
```

is compiled to something like this

```
(123)(123)?(123)?
```

Which makes it bigger than the maximum length

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that the regex compiler shouldn't behave that way, you really shouldn't have encountered this problem.  Inside the parentheses, your regex matches exactly one character from a specific set--the definition of a character class.  The correct way to write your regex is to list all the characters inside one set of square brackets and forego the parentheses:

```
/^[a-z0-9 ,'.!?]{1,4000}$/i
```

That works fine, as this [demo](http://ideone.com/d98qis) shows.  However, it *was* the parentheses that were causing the error (even non-capturing parens cause it), and that doesn't seem right to me, even if they were unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was an un-escaped `?` character

You need to escape it with not one, but to forward slashes `\\`

My regexp went from `(?340202)` to `(\\?340202)`