# "Compiled regex exceeds size limit of 10485760 bytes." error when defining the pattern property in a Pydantic Field

Tags: python, regex, pydantic

## Original question

I'm trying to define a Pydantic model with a string field that matches the following regex pattern: `^(\/[\w-]{1,255}){1,64}\/?$`, which should be used to validate expressions that match the form: `/alphanumeric-slugs-no-longer-than-255-chars/separated-by-slashes/no-more-than-64-slugs/`.

Basically, I want to match 1 to 64 slugs, each of max length 255, separated by slashes. This because after validation, I want to split the field into slugs by the slashes and save each slug in a database.

However, when I define my Pydantic model with the field as an `Annotated` string `Field` specifying the regex pattern like so:

```py
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: Annotated[str, Field(pattern=r"^(\/[\w-]{1,255}){1,64}\/?$"]
```

I'm met with the following error traceback:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.SchemaError: Error building "function-after" validator:
  SchemaError: Error building "function-wrap" validator:
  SchemaError: Error building "model" validator:
  SchemaError: Error building "model-fields" validator:
  SchemaError: Field "full_path":
  SchemaError: Error building "default" validator:
  SchemaError: Error building "str" validator:
  SchemaError: Compiled regex exceeds size limit of 10485760 bytes.
```

I tried to define a `field_validator` instead, and use the `re.match` function from the standard library to add the regex validation like so:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: str

    @field_validator("my_field")
    @classmethod
    def my_field_matches_regex(cls, v: str) -> str:
        if not re.match(r"^(\/[\w-]{1,255}){1,64}\/?$", v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid format, must match the regex pattern: ^(\/[\w-]{1,255}){1,64}\/?$")
        return v
```

This approach actually worked. However, I was hoping to take advantage of the simplicity of the `Field` when defining the regex pattern. I'm not sure why this error is thrown with the `Field`'s `pattern` property and not with the `re.match` approach.

---

## More information about the problem

- Python version: `3.12`
- Pydantic version: `2.6.1`

As @InSync pointed out below, this is not a runtime error but a compile time error emitted by Rust. Further digging into Pydantic's documentation does in fact show that it uses the [Rust regex implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) as its default [`regex_engine`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/api/pydantic_core_schema/#pydantic_core.core_schema.CoreConfig).

The original question is asking *why* does this behavior happen when working with a Pydantic's `Field` and not with `re.match`. Turns out, these two approaches use underlying different regex engines.

### Testing the two approaches

I tested the two engines with the same pattern `^(\/[\w-]{1,255}){1,64}\/?$` on regex101 and got these results:

- [Python engine](https://regex101.com/r/UWieis/1): passes 15 tests. Tested for valid characters, invalid characters, 64 slugs, more than 64 slugs, 255 characters per slug, more than 255 characters per slug, longest valid combination possible, extra characters after longest valid combination. Average test completion is 0 ms. The most inefficient query (last one) took 65156 steps and resolved in 5 ms. Was not able to replicate a catastrophic backtracking error.
- [Regex engine](https://regex101.com/r/kDngyJ/1): got `engine error` - `Compiled regex exceeds size limit of 10485760 bytes.`

#### Bonus

Tested the pattern `^(\/[\w-]+)+\/?$` and got these results:

- [Python engine](https://regex101.com/r/uHIeML/1): passes 10 tests (couldn't replicate string length tests). The most inefficient query is just writing a lot of valid characters until an invalid character. Average test completion is 0 ms. Got one with more than 10000 in length that took 40292 steps and resolved in 2 ms. Was not able to replicate a catastrophic backtracking error.
- [Regex engine](https://regex101.com/r/QrCq6O/1): passed the same 10 tests. Average test completion is 0 ms. Same inefficient string resolved in 2 ms.

Tested the pattern `^(\/[\w-]+){64}\/?$` and this one was more surprising. Got these results:

- [Python engine](https://regex101.com/r/pEsmDW/1): passes 13 tests, fails 1 very inefficient test of more than 64 slugs 10000 characters long each. Average test completion is 0 ms.
- [Regex engine](https://regex101.com/r/fuCIqk/1): passes the 14 tests. However, all tests are suddenly more slow (30 ms - 60 ms to complete). The most inefficient query takes upwards of 130ms to be resolved.

### Motivation about the original question

I was not able to find the error `Compiled regex exceeds size limit of 10485760 bytes.` when working on Python with Pydantic. This question is aimed to helps other that encounter the same error understand why does this happen (I didn't know that this was a Rust error until it was pointed out to me), and how can they fix it (in Pydantic that is).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The duplicate target is about a runtime behaviour. This one is about a compile time error.

Comment: It is the same thing: catastrophic backtracking with `(A+)+` pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not. The "*Compiled regex exceeds size limit*" *compile time* error is emitted by Rust, whose [regex implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) guarantees linear time matching, to boot.

Comment: @InSync thanks for pointing out that it was a Rust error. Edited the question to add more information

Comment: Regarding your *Bonus* section, you should do the testing on your dev environment. Regex101 seems to run on the client side (possibly with WASM), and its Python engine is emulated only.

Answer (score 1):

Googling similar issues, I was met with the following [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976303/php-why-am-i-being-warned-that-my-regular-expression-is-too-large) that shows a similar problem when compiling a regex in PHP using the curly braces to limit the input size to a specific range.

[@Mariano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988643/21323912) and [@Richard Deurwaarder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33976577/21323912) answers pointed me to the fact that using these nested quantifier ranges is creating an inefficient regular expression that is also very big after compilation.

Using the `+` quantifier instead and defining the regex pattern as `^(\/[\w-]+)+\/?$` doesn't throw any errors and compiles the [Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic) field successfully.

```py
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: Annotated[str, Field(pattern=r"^(\/[\w-]+)+\/?$"]
```

The downside is that the regex can no longer control the slug size nor the maximum number of slugs. For this specific use case, I can make do with this approach since I'm setting the restriction of the slug size on the database level too, so it will throw an error if they exceed the 255 characters limit. I can also check for the number of slugs after splitting the field.

```py
@some_atomic_transaction_decorator
def split_and_save_field(field: str, max_slugs: int = 64):
    slugs = field.split("/")
    if len(slugs) > max_slugs:
        raise ValueError(f"Slugs can't exceed maximum number of slugs: {max_slugs}")
    for slug in slugs:
        try:
            some_save_in_db(slug)
        except SomeDatabaseError:
            raise ValueError(f"Slug format not valid: {slug}")
```

**Bonus:** I tried the pattern `^(\/[\w-]+){1,64}\/?$` and this one compiles successfully, so I can skip the length check after splitting. This goes to show the culprit here is probably the nested quantifier ranges.

Comment: Hopefully this answer helps other that encounter the same problem when defining a regex pattern in a Pydantic `Field`. I couldn't find the exact error traceback anywhere

Comment: What is the result if you emulate an atomic group: `^(?:(?=(/[\w-]{1,255}))\1){1,64}/?$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that one throws a `SchemaError: regex parse error` on the `(?=` part, with description `error: look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte further digging showed that Pydantic uses the Rust regex crate as its default regex engine. As pointed out by this [issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7058#issue-1843635705), the Rust implementation doesn't support those features